# How do energy eigenstates go between Landau levels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, quantum-hall-effect

In the standard presentation of Landau levels, we find that the energy levels of free electrons in a solid of area $A$ and perpendicular field $B$ are separated in energy by
$$\Delta E = \hbar \omega_B$$
and each Landau level has degeneracy 
$$n = \frac{AB}{\Phi_0}$$
where $\Phi_0 = h/e$ is the quantum of flux.

However, I can't see how this picture makes sense as $B$ changes. As we change $B$, the energy of each quantum state should change continuously. However, if we want to maintain the structure of the Landau levels shown above, then quantum states would have to either 'jump' from one Landau level to another (not continuous) or be in between Landau levels at some point.

Neither of these makes much sense to me. What actually happens to the spectrum as we change $B$?

Comment: Excited states move towards the edge, come down in energy, and then move away from the edge. In other words, there's a band crossing at the edge that allows states from the upper band to move to the lower band. This is similar to what happens in adiabatic charge pumping.

Comment: In the 3D case movement along the magnetic field direction is not constrained, so the full energy is $h\omega_c(n + 1/2) + hk_z/2m$ for magnetic field $H||z$. This means, that electrons occupy a number of parabolas separated by cyclotron energy. When the magnetic field is increased, parabolas are pulled up and become depopulated, but there is always the finite number of them touching Fermi level. In 2D case the comment above applies, I believe.